# allure report getting blank page on index.html

Tags: automation, testng, allure

The build is successful[enter image description here][1] but the I'm getting a blank report on browsers[enter image description here][2].

[Console Image][3]

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.finigree</groupId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.1</aspectj.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache-extras.beanshell</groupId>
        <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
        <version>2.0b5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.ashot</groupId>
        <artifactId>ashot</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>23.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180130</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>browsermob-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ru.yandex.qatools.allure/allure-report-data -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-report-data</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-attachments -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-attachments</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>./testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <allure.results.directory>${project.build.directory}/allure-results
                    </allure.results.directory>
                    <application.properties>./application.properties
                    </application.properties>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>allure-site</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                 <fork>true</fork>
                <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin\javac</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<!-- profiles -->
<profiles>
    <!-- browsers -->
    <profile>
        <id>firefox</id>
        <properties>
            <capabilities>/firefox.capabilities</capabilities>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>chrome</id>
        <properties>
            <capabilities>/chrome.capabilities</capabilities>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>ie</id>
        <properties>
            <capabilities>/ie.capabilities</capabilities>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>safari</id>
        <properties>
            <capabilities>/safari.capabilities</capabilities>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>phantomjs</id>
        <properties>
            <capabilities>/phantomjs.capabilities</capabilities>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>opera</id>
        <properties>
            <capabilities>/opera.capabilities</capabilities>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>htmlunit</id>
        <properties>
            <capabilities>/htmlunit.capabilities</capabilities>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <!-- environments -->
    <profile>
        <id>localhost</id>
        <properties>
            <site.url>http://localhost/</site.url>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>devhost</id>
        <properties>
            <site.url>http://devhost/</site.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>testhost</id>
        <properties>
            <site.url>http://testhost/</site.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prodhost</id>
        <properties>
            <site.url>http://prodhost.com/</site.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <!-- grid -->
    <profile>
        <id>nogrid</id>
        <properties>
            <grid.url></grid.url>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>grid</id>
        <properties>
            <grid.url>http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/</grid.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<artifactId>Automation</artifactId>
```

added pom.xml file and attached the console screenshot [3]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGklJ.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwHLS.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XchAN.png

Comment: Have you downloaded installed `allure` program on your PC? And do you have `allure` in pom.xml?

Comment: yes, installed and had dependency on pom.xml

Comment: please show screenshot of the version in terminal/console and full pom.xml

Comment: @Villa_7 details are attached above

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify `allure-maven` plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <allureDownloadUrl>https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/releases/download/2.7.0/allure-2.7.0.zip</allureDownloadUrl>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```